# Resistor voltage sharply drops

Tags: capacitor, ltspice

Why does the voltage across R1 sharply drops, then slowly go to the ground in the simulations?

However, when I probe VC1 the cap does discharge in an exponential manner, as expected. Should the voltage across R1, have a similar exponential from 12V to 0V?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also note that the switch model statement gives it an on resistance of 1Ω which will slightly affect results.  If you wanted to make the switch more "transparent", consider `Ron=1u Roff=1Gig` or similar.  But also note that the 12V supply has zero internal resistance, so could theoretically deliver infinite current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why does the voltage across R1 sharply drops, then slowly go to the
> ground in the simulations?*

R1 never sees 12 volts when the switch opens because of the potential division caused by R5. Because R5 is 3 kΩ and R1 is 470 Ω the voltage across R1 is only 0.1354 of the capacitor voltage and that is just about what you see in the image in your question. So, R1 immediately drops from 12 volts to 1.625 volts when the switch opens.